# Object.assign workaround in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using `ES6` in the following code in the angular app. `Object.assign` works as expected anywhere but IE.

```
const resetSuppItem = (item) => {
      Object.assign(vm.suppitem, _.pick($scope.item, ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']));     
    }
```

What could be the workaround so it works in IE?

Comment: You can use `_.extend` / `_.assignIn` Seems you are using lodash

Comment: Use the polyfill from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: @Satpal that's the best solution since I use lodash, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option will be to use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). If not use this perhaps:

```
function newAssign(target) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var source = arguments[i];
        for (var key in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                target[key] = source[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Where is arguments coming from?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use jQuery method [extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), which is pretty simple and works in both IE and Chrome:

```js
var user = {Name: 'Marshall', Surname: 'Depp'};
var newUserObj = $.extend({}, user);
    
newUserObj.Country = 'USA';
newUserObj.Mobile= 'xxxxxxxxxx';

console.log(user);
console.log(newUserObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
function assign(target, ...sources) {
    var result = target;

    sources.forEach(function(source) {
    var keys = Object.keys(source);
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        result[key] = source[key];
    });
});
    return result;
}
```

pretty much similar to Object.assign()

example:

```
let one = { name:"vamshi"}

let two = assign({},one)

two.name  = "somenew name" // this wont update one.name
```